# Why the recorded audio data only use half of the buffer (WaveIn)?

Tags: c++, windows, audio

I'm trying to record audio data from the microphone and save in files. The problem is that the wavein device only uses half the buffer specified in the wave header. In particular, only first 2000 points in the file from the audio, the rest of the file reads like the following

```
-12851
-12851
-12851
-12851
.....
```

Not clear what goes wrong. What I find is that if I change the following line of code from

```
_header[i].dwBufferLength = bpbuff;
```

to

```
_header[i].dwBufferLength = 2*bpbuff;
```

then all 4000 values are indeed the audio input. But obviously this is not the right way to get the problem fixed. Any thoughts?

Here's the full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
HANDLE hEvent_BufferReady;
#define Samplerate 2000
#define nSec  3

BOOL BufferReady;

enum { NUM_BUF = 8 };

int _iBuf;
int prevBuf;

void CALLBACK myWaveInProc(HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwInstance, DWORD dwParam1, DWORD dwParam2)
{
    WAVEHDR *pHdr=NULL;
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WIM_CLOSE:
            cout << "waveInProc()... WIM_CLOSE" << endl;
            break;

        case WIM_DATA:
            {
                cout << "waveInProc()... WIM_DATA : " <<endl;
                SetEvent(hEvent_BufferReady);
            }
            break;

        case WIM_OPEN:
            cout << "waveInProc()... WIM_OPEN" << endl;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    hEvent_BufferReady=CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE, FALSE, NULL);

    WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
    pFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM; // simple, uncompressed format
    pFormat.nChannels = 1; // 1=mono, 2=stereo
    pFormat.nSamplesPerSec = Samplerate; // 44100
    pFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16; // 16 for high quality, 8 for telephone-grade
    pFormat.nBlockAlign = pFormat.nChannels*pFormat.wBitsPerSample/8; 
    pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = (pFormat.nSamplesPerSec)*(pFormat.nChannels)*(pFormat.wBitsPerSample)/8; 
    pFormat.cbSize=0;

    HWAVEIN hWaveIn;

    unsigned long result;

    WAVEHDR _header [NUM_BUF];
    short int  *_pBuf;
    size_t bpbuff = (pFormat.nSamplesPerSec) * (pFormat.nChannels) * (pFormat.wBitsPerSample)/8;

    result = waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER,&pFormat, (DWORD)myWaveInProc, 0L, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);

    _pBuf = new short int [bpbuff * NUM_BUF];

    // initialize all headers in the queue
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_BUF; i++ )
    {
        _header[i].lpData = (LPSTR)&_pBuf [i * bpbuff];
        _header[i].dwBufferLength = bpbuff;
        _header[i].dwFlags = 0L;
        _header[i].dwLoops = 0L;
        waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, & _header[i], sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveInAddBuffer (hWaveIn, & _header[i], sizeof (WAVEHDR));
    }

    _iBuf = 0;
    int _prevBuf = NUM_BUF - 1;

    unsigned char* tempchar;
    waveInStart(hWaveIn);
    for(int iter=0;iter<5;iter++)
    {

        do {
        } while (!(_header[_iBuf].dwFlags & WHDR_DONE));
        waveInUnprepareHeader (hWaveIn, &_header[_iBuf], sizeof (WAVEHDR));

        std::ostringstream fn;
        fn << "file" << iter << ".txt";
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open (fn.str());


        for(int i=0;i<bpbuff;i++)
        {
            myfile<<_pBuf[_iBuf*bpbuff + i]<<"\n";
        }
        myfile.close();


        int prevBuf = _iBuf - 1;
        if (prevBuf < 0)
            prevBuf = NUM_BUF - 1;

        _header [prevBuf].lpData = (LPSTR)&_pBuf [prevBuf * bpbuff];
        _header [prevBuf].dwBufferLength = bpbuff;
        _header [prevBuf].dwFlags = 0L;
        _header [prevBuf].dwLoops = 0L;

        waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, & _header[_iBuf], sizeof(WAVEHDR));
        waveInAddBuffer (hWaveIn, & _header[_iBuf], sizeof (WAVEHDR));

        ++_iBuf;
        if (_iBuf == NUM_BUF)   _iBuf = 0;

    }


    waveInClose(hWaveIn);


    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    getchar();


    CloseHandle(hEvent_BufferReady);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a buffer overrun or other UB. Did you try debugging your program? Narrowing down the problem to a few lines of code?

Comment: Okay then you know best.

Answer (score 1):

[`WAVEHDR::dwBufferLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743837):

> `dwBufferLength` - Length, in bytes, of the buffer.

Your code:

```
_pBuf = new short int [bpbuff * NUM_BUF];

// initialize all headers in the queue
for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_BUF; i++ )
{
    _header[i].lpData = (LPSTR)&_pBuf [i * bpbuff];
    _header[i].dwBufferLength = bpbuff;
```

Your buffer is `bpbuff * sizeof (short int)` bytes long. However you route it to the API to get it filled with `bpbuff` bytes of data only. Hence, the buffer is only filled partially and the rest of it holds uninitialized data (which you see as -12851, see [`0xCDCDCDCD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/127404/868014)).

You need to make it:

```
    _header[i].dwBufferLength = bpbuff * sizeof *_pBuf;
```

Comment: This exactly fixes the problem. I was suspecting that this is related to the data type, and experimented with data type a little bit, but didn't have a clear understanding about what dwBuferLength really needs to be.  

Thanks!